# Why are negative numbers starting with zero giving different output?

Tags: php, math

Why are negative numbers starting with zero giving different output?

```
<?php
echo -0222;
```

Output: **-146** Why?

Ex: https://glot.io/snippets/eprnnw04bd

Comment: That is octal notation.

Comment: that's one of the questions i use to test new programmers